# Android Gallery with bitmap

Tags: android

Can someone please give me a example of android gallery using bitmap properties. I have created a gallery without it which is giving me out of memory error. I am new to android programming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each application is assigned a memory limit by VM. It could be 16Mb, 32 Mb ... depending on the device.
So handling bitmaps is a very important thing. Recycling the bitmap's or using softreferences, LRU Cache, disk Cache are helpfull to avoid VM Budget error.

Refer to 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
for more details on handling bitmaps.